# Can't compile GDAL on OSX 1.11.6 due to libiconv link error

Tags: c++, macos, osx-elcapitan, gdal, iconv

I recently upgraded my OSX machine to OSX El Capitan (1.11.6) and have run into an issue with compiling GDAL 1.11.x.  I've tried this with 1.11.4 and 1.11.5 and I get the same result.

We use GDAL 1.11.x as a dependency on one of our projects -- for now we can't update to GDAL 2.x because there are legacy software issues that are stuck with some functions that were deprecated out in GDAL 2.x ...

Since moving my machine to El Capitan, GDAL 1.11.x fails to build with the following linker error message down towards the final link step:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make -C pdf
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `default'.
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make libgdal.la
/bin/sh /test/gdal-1.11.5/libtool --mode=link   g++    -L/opt/local/lib -lgeos_c  -lsqlite3 -lpthread -ldl               -liconv  -L/opt/local/lib -lxml2 -lz -lpthread -liconv -lm  -o libgdal.la /test/gdal-1.11.5/frmts/o/*.lo /test/gdal-1.11.5/gcore/*.lo /test/gdal-1.11.5/port/*.lo /test/gdal-1.11.5/alg/*.lo /test/gdal-1.11.5/ogr/ogrsf_frmts/o/*.lo ./ogr/ogrgeometryfactory.lo ./ogr/ogrpoint.lo ./ogr/ogrcurve.lo ./ogr/ogrlinestring.lo ./ogr/ogrlinearring.lo ./ogr/ogrpolygon.lo ./ogr/ogrutils.lo ./ogr/ogrgeometry.lo ./ogr/ogrgeometrycollection.lo ./ogr/ogrmultipolygon.lo ./ogr/ogrsurface.lo ./ogr/ogrmultipoint.lo ./ogr/ogrmultilinestring.lo ./ogr/ogr_api.lo ./ogr/ogrfeature.lo ./ogr/ogrfeaturedefn.lo ./ogr/ogrfeaturequery.lo ./ogr/ogrfeaturestyle.lo ./ogr/ogrfielddefn.lo ./ogr/ogrspatialreference.lo ./ogr/ogr_srsnode.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_proj4.lo ./ogr/ogr_fromepsg.lo ./ogr/ogrct.lo ./ogr/ogr_opt.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_esri.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_pci.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_usgs.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_dict.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_panorama.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_ozi.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_erm.lo ./ogr/swq.lo ./ogr/swq_expr_node.lo ./ogr/swq_parser.lo ./ogr/swq_select.lo ./ogr/swq_op_registrar.lo ./ogr/swq_op_general.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_validate.lo ./ogr/ogr_srs_xml.lo ./ogr/ograssemblepolygon.lo ./ogr/ogr2gmlgeometry.lo ./ogr/gml2ogrgeometry.lo ./ogr/ogr_expat.lo ./ogr/ogrpgeogeometry.lo ./ogr/ogrgeomediageometry.lo ./ogr/ogr_geocoding.lo ./ogr/osr_cs_wkt.lo ./ogr/osr_cs_wkt_parser.lo ./ogr/ogrgeomfielddefn.lo \
    -rpath /usr/local/lib \
    -no-undefined \
    -version-info 19:5:18

libtool: link: g++ -dynamiclib  -o .libs/libgdal.1.dylib <snipped out the rest of the gigantic link line/>

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_iconv", referenced from:
      CPLRecodeIconv(char const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
      CPLRecodeFromWCharIconv(wchar_t const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
  "_iconv_close", referenced from:
      CPLRecodeIconv(char const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
      CPLRecodeFromWCharIconv(wchar_t const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
  "_iconv_open", referenced from:
      CPLRecodeIconv(char const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
      CPLRecodeFromWCharIconv(wchar_t const*, char const*, char const*) in cpl_recode_iconv.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[1]: *** [libgdal.la] Error 1
make: *** [check-lib] Error 2
```

I'm doing a [minimal configuration](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnUnixWithMinimizedDrivers) based on documentation I found on GDAL's website:

```
$ ./configure --with-netcdf=no \
              --with-jpeg=no \
              --with-threads \
              --with-ogr \
              --with-geos \
              --with-libz=internal \
              --with-libtiff=internal \
              --with-geotiff=internal \
              --without-gif \
              --without-pg \
              --without-grass \
              --without-libgrass \
              --without-cfitsio \
              --without-pcraster \
              --without-png \
              --without-gif \
              --without-ogdi \
              --without-fme \
              --without-hdf4 \
              --without-hdf5 \
              --without-jasper \
              --without-ecw \
              --without-kakadu \
              --without-mrsid \
              --without-jp2mrsid \
              --without-bsb \
              --without-grib \
              --without-mysql \
              --without-ingres \
              --without-xerces \
              --without-expat \
              --without-odbc \
              --without-curl \
              --without-dwgdirect \
              --without-idb \
              --without-sde \
              --without-perl \
              --without-php \
              --without-ruby \
              --with-hide-internal-symbols \
              --disable-rpath
```

I am using macports and have libiconv installed...

```
$ sudo port install libiconv
--->  Cleaning libiconv
--->  Scanning binaries for linking errors
--->  No broken files found.
```

/opt/local/lib is also in my **LD_LIBRARY_PATH** and DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH and I verified that libiconv is in /opt/local/lib as well:

```
> ll /opt/local/lib/*iconv*
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin    16B Jan 29  2016 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.dylib@ -> libiconv.2.dylib
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   1.0M Jan 29  2016 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.a
-rw-r--r--  1 root  admin   1.0M Jan 29  2016 /opt/local/lib/libiconv.2.dylib
```

Has anyone run across something like this?  Any ideas?

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this error in a file that uses gdal, and I had to add this in my cmakelist:
optimized iconv debug iconv

I know that's a little different than what you're looking for.  Did you try with Gdal 1.11.1?

Also, did you start out by cleaning it?  We run into issues with that all the time.

I look in my PATH, not my LD_LIBRARY_PATH (that's blank), and see /usr/bin, which is where my iconv is.

Are there any flags to set in the GDAL config file or makefile?  Sorry to be generic.  Someone else in my group built this.  Added: I see the flags you list above, but maybe there's a GDAL flag to use to tell it where iconv is.

Comment: Another thing you can do is build iconv by itself and tell GDAL where to get it from.

Comment: Also, did you run configure?  I'm assuming you did, because you must be using what came from configure command to do make. If you don't think you need to configure after your upgrade of os, you might be wrong.  Just a suggestion.  I usually don't answer questions here, and I know this one is an older one.

Comment: There are some flags at this link that you didn't use:  https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/BuildingOnMac

Comment: Another thought, is gdal looking for iconv dylib or another version?